# Angularjs: Select and focus of an element in directive link

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get a text input field selected and focused from the beginning with my custom directive.

Input Field:

```
<input type="text" value="Preset Value" select-on-load />
```

Custom Directive:

```
app.directive('selectOnLoad', function () {
// Linker function
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.focus().select();
    }
};
```

});

But I only get a javscript error saying that focus/select is not a function.
How else should I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular's jqLite (built-in light version of jQuery) doesn't support `.focus()`.

You'll need to get the actual DOM element and use the Javascript's built-in `.focus()`

```
element[0].focus()
```

(`element[0]` gets the DOM element object from a jqLite wrapper `element`)

With `.select()` it is a bit trickier if you are trying to select the text that comes via `ng-model`, because by the time the `link` function runs, the `ng-model`'s value has not yet been interpolated and inserted into the DOM.

You'd need to wait until the end of the digest cycle, and the common way I've seen this being done is via `$timeout`:

```
$timeout(function(){
  element[0].select();
});
```

Comment: Ok cool, the focus works but the select doesn't. I set the content of the text input in my controller via the ng-model, does that happen after the select(), meaning that I have to delay the select?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to delay the select until the `ng-model` value is compiled and linked. Updated the answer

Comment: Ok, that's it. Pretty annyoing tho. Thought the link gets called when alll is finished.

Comment: "all is finished" as in - compiled and pre-linked, but the value in the input hasn't yet interpolated